# multiple dependent dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have used the following code to run two different dependent dropdown list. Subdivision depends on District and Dress depends on Gender. Its not working. Where is the problem? Can we use two functions like that?

```
$(function(){
var $cat = $("#cat"),
    $subcat = $("#subcat");  

$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
  });

 var $cat1 = $("#cat1"),
    $subcat1 = $("#subcat1");  

$cat1.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat1.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat1.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat1.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat1.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat1.prop("disabled",false);
}); 

 });


District: <select name="dis"  id="cat" required><option></option><option 
>North </option><option >Unakoti</option></select> 

Subdivision: <select name="subd" id="subcat"   required><option></option>
<option rel="North" value="Dharmanagar">Dharmanagar</option>
 <option rel="North" value="Panisagar">Panisagar</option>
<option rel="North" value="Kanchanpur">Kanchanpur</option>

<option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kailasahar">Kailasahar</option>
<option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kumarghat" >Kumarghat</option></select> 


Gender: <select name="gen"  id="cat1" required><option></option><option >M 
</option><option >F</option></select> 

Dress: <select name="dre" id="subcat1"   required><option></option>
<option rel="M" value="D1">D1</option>
<option rel="M" value="D2">D2</option>
<option rel="M" value="D3">D3</option>

<option  rel="F" value="D4">D4</option>
<option  rel="F" value="D5" >D5</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a good practice to have to have multiple ready() functions. You can remove the second $(function(){ }) and add all your code in the first instance of that function. This is a function that will be used after the DOM element have loaded and you can put as much code as you want in it. There is no need to define it again.
      In addition, if you want to set $subcat.prop("disabled",true) there is no need to add return. You can use if(!_rel) $subcat.prop("disabled",true);